# How to Convert HttpResponseMessage to IList format in XUnit.net?

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, xunit.net

I am trying to get the contents from Web API while doing the unit testing.
I am using XUnit for unit testing.
I want to compare list (expected and actual) once I can read the content.
I am trying it in following way:

```
IList<SearchReportsResult> returnedReportList = null;
Assert.True(response.TryGetContentValue<List<SearchReportsResult>>(out returnedReportList));
Assert.NotNull(returnedReportList);
```

Please let me know how can I parse the content?

Comment: If you get a non-null `IList<SearchReportsResult>`, you don't need to *parse* anything, as it's already an object in memory.

Comment: Okay. But, I could not evaluate Assert.True statement. If I could do that I can check NotNull.

Comment: Why can't you evaluate `Assert.True`?

Comment: Thanks Mark for quick reply.I am trying to evaluate Assert.True. But, did not get success. For that only,  I am asking help.